# adding a column in table with name retrived from nsdictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, nsdictionary, alter-table

In iPhone application,  how to pass `NSDictionary` as a parameter to a method which has `sqlite3` “`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` ”command and I need to retrieve the `OBJECTS` and `KEYS` from the `NSDictionary` to give it in column name and datatype. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

to pass NSDictionary as a parameter to a function -

-(void) addColumn:(NSDictionary *) dictionary